# Runtime Error 2293

Tags: security, ms-access, outlook

I am currently using Microsoft Outlook 2013 and Access 2013. When I upgraded to 2013, there was a security update that doesn't allow the `SendObject` method in Visual Basic. It's not allowing me to send emails from my program in Access.

Is there a way around this security update?

Comment: I have been using vbMAPI from EverythingAccess.com (http://www.everythingaccess.com/vbMAPI.asp) for many years. It is well worth the low price.

Answer (score 1):

There was no such security updates. Most probably you are talking about the standard security prompt in Outlook. See [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) for possible options.

I'd recommend using the [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) component which allows to supress such prompts or avoid errors in the code.